# Apache FOP | custom fonts | relative URL not working

Tags: aem, apache-fop

I have got configuration file to load custom fonts for Apache FOP. I am struggling to configure embed-url on server so that font url changes as per server domain.

I have tried embed-url property value as:

**Non working embed-urls:**

- embed-url="context:/etc/designs/projectName/clientlibs/pdffonts/Batang.ttf"
- embed-url="file:/etc/designs/projectName/clientlibs/pdffonts/Batang.ttf"

**Working embed-url:**

- embed-url="http://localhost:4503/etc/designs/projectName/clientlibs/pdffonts/Batang.ttf"

Somehow I can't seems to find proper syntax here. I am using FOP with AEM 6.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">
    <renderers>
        <renderer mime="application/pdf">
            <fonts>
                <font kerning="yes"
                    embed-url="context:/etc/designs/projectName/clientlibs/pdffonts/Batang.ttf" -- this doesn't
                    embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="SimSun" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes"
                    embed-url="file:/etc/designs/projectName/clientlibs/pdffonts/Batang.ttf" -- this doesn't
                    embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="Batang" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
                <font kerning="yes"
                    embed-url="http://localhost:4503/etc/designs/projectName/clientlibs/pdffonts/Batang.ttf" -- this works
                    embedding-mode="subset">
                    <font-triplet name="Batang" style="normal" weight="normal" />
                </font>
            </fonts>
        </renderer>
    </renderers>
</fop>
```

Comment: As I was working with AEM, I end up creating multiple configuration files for Apache FOP per run mode. This met my requirement but I guess there must be better way to do this.

Comment: is it possible to import one config to another? i need the same fonts in every config but different pdf-x-mode settings. any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**"Starting point" for relative paths:**

- if the configuration file has a `font-base` element (as a direct child of the document root element), its value is used to resolve relative font paths
- otherwise, the value of the `base` element is used instead
- the default configuration file included in the distribution has the element `<base>.</base>`, meaning that relative paths must be interpreted as relative to the position of the configuration file

Note that the values of `font-base` and `base` can be relative too, in which case they refer to the configuration file path.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<fop version="1.0">

  <base>.</base>

  <font-base>/Users/lfurini/Library/Fonts</font-base>
  <!-- other possible examples:
  <font-base>.</font-base>
  <font-base>../fonts</font-base>
  --> 

  <!-- ... -->
</fop>
```

**Relative paths syntax:**

- you don't need `context:` or `file:`
- if the `embed-url` starts with `/` it's an absolute path, otherwise it's a relative one referring to the "starting point" defined before
- relative paths can contain `../` to go back up in the folder hierarchy, if needed

  ```
  <!-- directly in the base folder -->
  <font kerning="yes" embed-url="font1.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="font1" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>

  <!-- in a "sister" folder -->
  <font kerning="yes" embed-url="../otherFonts/font2.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="font2" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>

  <!-- in a sub-folder -->
  <font kerning="yes" embed-url="specialFonts/font3.ttf">
    <font-triplet name="font3" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>

  <!-- absolute path -->
  <font kerning="yes" embed-url="/Users/lfurini/Library/Fonts/font4.ttf" embedding-mode="subset">
    <font-triplet name="font4" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
  </font>
  ```

(tested with FOP 1.1, 2.0 and 2.1)

*(disclosure: I'm a FOP developer, though not very active nowadays)*

Comment: but it's not  a relative path, it's hardcoded path. Relative is when you use contextPath of whole application. Your solution  "conflicts with portability".

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by adding full path upto application from code. and added later patr from config file.

> fopFactory.setBaseURL(this.getServletContext().getInitParameter("my_path"));

In config

> embed-url="fonts/newfont.ttf"

Answer (score 0):

For FOP-2.1 there is a patch for "Allow relative paths to font files/directories" at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FOP-2627.